# Undetected Screen on my laptop since kenel 3.13.0-45

Tags: drivers, kernel

In Kubuntu 14.04 LTS, since kernel update 3.13.0-45, the laptop display remains black after boot.

The system is running (I can fully access it via *rsh*) and the graphic card also (for external display).

During boot, the display shows the grub dialog, the Kubuntu logo is larger than usual and then went black.

In Xorg.0.log, three `s` lines are missing from previous versions :

```
(II) intel(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 4377
(II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
(II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.00  1366 1407 1434 1500  768 771 775 788 -hsync -vsync (47.3 kHz eP)
```

In `syslog` and `dmesg` a new line appeared :

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
```

The graphic controller is *ValleyView Gen7* from Intel Corporation, and graphic driver is *i915* (`/lib/modules/3.13.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko`)

This problem is "stable" in kernel version 45 and 46 and 47 and 48 and 49. I can still use the laptop with kernel 44 or less.

Answer (score 0):

I think this bug is for the same issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1427646